# Graph processing increasingly gets slower on titan + dynamoDB (local) as more vertices/edges are added

Tags: titan, dynamo-local

I am working with titan 1.0 using AWS dynamoDB local implementation as storage backend on a 16GB machine. My use case involves generating graphs periodically containing vertices & edges in the order of 120K. Every time I generate a new graph in-memory, I check the graph stored in DB and either (i) add vertices/edges that do not exist, or (ii) update properties if they already exist (existence is determined by 'Label' and a 'Value' attribute). Note that the 'Value' property is indexed. Transactions are committed in batches of 500 vertices.

**Problem:** I find that this process gets slower each time I process a new graph (1st graph finished in 45 mins with empty db initially, 2nd took 2.5 hours, 3rd in 3.5 hours, 4th in 6 hours, 5th in 10 hours and so on). In fact, when processing a given graph, it is fairly quick at start time but progressively gets slower (initial batches take 2-4 secs and later on it increases to 100s of seconds for same batch size of 500 nodes; I also see sometimes it takes 1000-2000 secs for a batch). This is the processing time alone (see approach below); commit takes between 8-10 secs always.  I configured the jvm heap size to 10G, and I notice that when the app is running it is eventually using up all of it.

**Question:** Is this behavior to be expected? It seems to me something is wrong here (either in my [config](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4923794/local-graph.properties) / approach?). Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

**Approach:**

- Starting from the root node of the in-memory graph, I retrieve all child nodes and maintain a queue
- For each child node, I check to see if it exists in DB, else create new node, and update some properties

  ```
  Vertex dbVertex = dbgraph.traversal().V()
          .has(currentVertexInMem.label(), "Value",
                  (String) currentVertexInMem.value("Value"))
          .tryNext()
          .orElseGet(() -> createVertex(dbgraph, currentVertexInMem));

  if (dbVertex != null) {
      // Update Properties
      updateVertexProperties(dbgraph, currentVertexInMem, dbVertex);
  }

  // Add edge if necessary
  if (parentDBVertex != null) {
      GraphTraversal<Vertex, Edge> edgeIt = graph.traversal().V(parentDBVertex).outE()
              .has("EdgeProperty1", eProperty1) // eProperty1 is String input parameter
              .has("EdgeProperty2", eProperty2); // eProperty2 is Long input parameter

      Boolean doCreateEdge = true;
      Edge e = null;
      while (edgeIt.hasNext()) {
          e = edgeIt.next();
          if (e.inVertex().equals(dbVertex)) {
              doCreateEdge = false;
              break;
          }

      if (doCreateEdge) {
          e = parentDBVertex.addEdge("EdgeLabel", dbVertex, "EdgeProperty1", eProperty1, "EdgeProperty2", eProperty2);
      } 
      e = null;
      it = null;
  }

  ...

  if ((processedVertexCount.get() % 500 == 0) 
       || processedVertexCount.get() == verticesToProcess.get()) {                            
      graph.tx().commit();
  }
  ```

*Create function:*

```
public static Vertex createVertex(Graph graph, Vertex clientVertex) {
    Vertex newVertex = null; 
    switch (clientVertex.label()) {
    case "Label 1":
        newVertex = graph.addVertex(T.label, clientVertex.label(), "Value",
                clientVertex.value("Value"), 
                "Property1-1", clientVertex.value("Property1-1"), 
                "Property1-2", clientVertex.value("Property1-2"));
        break;

    case "Label 2":
        newVertex = graph.addVertex(T.label, clientVertex.label(), "Value",
                clientVertex.value("Value"), "Property2-1",
                clientVertex.value("Property2-1"),
                "Property2-2", clientVertex.value("Property2-2"));
        break;

    default:
        newVertex = graph.addVertex(T.label, clientVertex.label(), "Value",
                clientVertex.value("Value"));
        break;
    }
    return newVertex;
}
```

**Schema Def:** (Showing some of the indexes)
*Note:* 
   "EdgeLabel" = Constants.EdgeLabels.Uses
 
   "EdgeProperty1" = Constants.EdgePropertyKeys.EndpointId
   "EdgeProperty2" = Constants.EdgePropertyKeys.Timestamp

```
public void createSchema() {
    // Create Schema
    TitanManagement mgmt = dbgraph.openManagement();
    mgmt.set("cache.db-cache",true);

    // Vertex Properties
    PropertyKey value = mgmt.getPropertyKey(Constants.VertexPropertyKeys.Value);
    if (value == null) {
        value = mgmt.makePropertyKey(Constants.VertexPropertyKeys.Value).dataType(String.class).make();
        mgmt.buildIndex(Constants.GraphIndexes.ByValue, Vertex.class).addKey(value).buildCompositeIndex(); // INDEX
    }

    PropertyKey shapeSet = mgmt.getPropertyKey(Constants.VertexPropertyKeys.ShapeSet);
    if (shapeSet == null) {
        shapeSet = mgmt.makePropertyKey(Constants.VertexPropertyKeys.ShapeSet).dataType(String.class).cardinality(Cardinality.SET).make();
        mgmt.buildIndex(Constants.GraphIndexes.ByShape, Vertex.class).addKey(shapeSet).buildCompositeIndex();
    }
    ...

    // Edge Labels and Properties
    EdgeLabel uses = mgmt.getEdgeLabel(Constants.EdgeLabels.Uses);
    if (uses == null) {
        uses = mgmt.makeEdgeLabel(Constants.EdgeLabels.Uses).multiplicity(Multiplicity.MULTI).make();

        PropertyKey timestampE = mgmt.getPropertyKey(Constants.EdgePropertyKeys.Timestamp);
        if (timestampE == null) {
            timestampE = mgmt.makePropertyKey(Constants.EdgePropertyKeys.Timestamp).dataType(Long.class).make();
        }

        PropertyKey endpointIDE = mgmt.getPropertyKey(Constants.EdgePropertyKeys.EndpointId);
        if (endpointIDE == null) {
            endpointIDE = mgmt.makePropertyKey(Constants.EdgePropertyKeys.EndpointId).dataType(String.class).make();
        }

        // Indexes
        mgmt.buildEdgeIndex(uses, Constants.EdgeIndexes.ByEndpointIDAndTimestamp, Direction.BOTH, endpointIDE,
                timestampE);
    }

    mgmt.commit();
}
```

Comment: Did you define any indexes? If so, could you include those definitions in your question? http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/1.0.0/indexes.html

Comment: edited the question to include index definitions ...

Comment: How did you configure Gremlin's cache? Do you use parameterized queries? By default Gremlin retains every query in the cache until you run out of memory. You can [change that behavior](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#_cache_management), or parameterize your queries.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you experience is expected. Today, DynamoDB Local is a testing tool built on SQLite. If you need to support high TPS for large and periodic data loads, I recommend you use the DynamoDB service.